# Get all the TypeRep's in a value using generic programming

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

Is there a way to get a list of all the `TypeRep`'s inside a value using generic programming?

For instance, could one define a function:

```hs
typeReps :: (Data a, Typeable a) => a -> [TypeRep]
```

in such a way that:

```hs
>>> typeReps (1 :: Int, 'a')
[(Int, Char), Int, Char]

>>> typeReps (Foo ['a', 'b'])
[Foo, [Char], Char, Char]
```

I've tried

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module Example where

import Data.Data
import Data.Typeable

typeReps :: (Data a, Typeable a) => a -> TypeReps a
typeReps a = gfoldl step fcstr a
  where
    step :: forall d b. (Typeable d, Data d) =>  TypeReps (d -> b) -> d -> TypeReps b
    step tot d = tot <++> typeReps d

    fcstr :: forall g . g -> TypeReps g
    fcstr g  = TypeReps [typeOf a]
```

However this seems to duplicate the type `TypeRep`s in the result:

```hs
>>> typeReps ['a']
TypeReps {getTypes = [[Char],Char,[Char]]}
```

Furthermore, it looks a bit backwards that I'm not using `g` but `a` in the `fsctr` function above (and I cannot since I cannot constrain `g` to be `Typeable`).

I don't know if this can be solved in this way, and if not, I wonder whether there are other ways of approaching it.

Comment: As far as `Data` is concerned, a list `['a', 'b']` is really nested pairs `('a' : ('b' : []))` so that the duplication you see can be explained as `typeReps` "accounting" for these nested pairs. Do you mean to make a special case for `[]`, or do you have a higher level description of what you want to do that would make the result `[[Char], Char, Char]`?

Comment: Oh, that explains it! I would basically like to count the types of the values that occur in a structure, to have a measure of its size. So for instance, I'd expect `Foo [1, 2] ('a', 'b')` to return something like `[Foo, [Int], Int, Int, (Char, Char), Char, Char]`. I don't know if I defining my problem clearly or properly.

Comment: I think you might be better off hard coding special cases for recursive structures, unless you have a lot of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it looks like you are not taking into account that `[1,2,3]` is actually `1 : 2 : 3 : []` (where *each* tail subterm has type `[Int]`). You can just add a special case for lists:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.Data

-- | Returns 'Just' only for lists
--
-- This can surely be done more efficiently, but it does the job.
listTypeReps :: Data a => a -> Maybe [TypeRep]
listTypeReps x

  | typeRepTyCon (typeOf x) == listTyCon
  , toConstr x == toConstr ([] :: [()])   -- empty list
  = Just []

  | typeRepTyCon (typeOf x) == listTyCon
  , toConstr x == toConstr [()]           -- cons
  , [headTs, _] <- gmapQ typeReps x
  , [_, Just tailTs] <- gmapQ listTypeReps x
  = Just (headTs ++ tailTs)

  | otherwise
  = Nothing

listTyCon :: TyCon
listTyCon = typeRepTyCon (typeOf ([] :: [()]))

-- | Get the types of subterms
typeReps :: Data a => a -> [TypeRep]
typeReps x = typeOf x : case listTypeReps x of
                          Just ts -> ts
                          Nothing -> concat (gmapQ typeReps x)
```

Try it out:

```
ghci> :set -XDeriveDataTypeable
ghci> data Foo = Foo [Int] (Char,Char) deriving (Data,Typeable)
ghci> typeReps $ Foo [1, 2] ('a', 'b')
[Foo,[Int],Int,Int,(Char,Char),Char,Char]
```

Comment: Does that also work on `Foo [] ('a', 'b')` ? I ask because of the special case for the empty list.

Comment: @chi Yep it does: `[Foo,[Int],(Char,Char),Char,Char]`. The special case for the lists only treats the _subterms_ specially.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help! Just in case somebody is interested in solving this using `Generics`, here's the solution I found with this mechanism:

```hs
class Typeable a => HasTypeReps a where
  typeReps :: a -> [TypeRep]

  default typeReps :: (Generic a, GHasTypeReps (Rep a)) => a -> [TypeRep]
  typeReps a = typeOf a: gTypeReps (from a)

class GHasTypeReps f where
  gTypeReps :: f a -> [TypeRep]

instance GHasTypeReps U1 where
  gTypeReps U1 = []

instance (GHasTypeReps a, GHasTypeReps b) => GHasTypeReps (a :*: b) where
  gTypeReps (a :*: b) = gTypeReps a ++ gTypeReps b

instance (GHasTypeReps a, GHasTypeReps b) => GHasTypeReps (a :+: b) where
  gTypeReps (L1 a) = gTypeReps a
  gTypeReps (R1 b) = gTypeReps b

-- | We do need to do anything for the metadata.
instance (GHasTypeReps a) => GHasTypeReps (M1 i c a) where
    gTypeReps (M1 x) = gTypeReps x

-- | And the only interesting case, get the type of a type constructor
instance (HasTypeReps a) => GHasTypeReps (K1 i a) where
    gTypeReps (K1 x) = typeReps x

instance HasTypeReps a => HasTypeReps [a] where
  typeReps xs = typeOf xs: concatMap typeReps xs

instance (HasTypeReps a, HasTypeReps b) => HasTypeReps (a, b) where
  typeReps t@(a, b) = typeOf t: (typeReps a ++ typeReps b)

instance HasTypeReps Char where
  typeReps x = [typeOf x]

instance HasTypeReps Int where
  typeReps x = [typeOf x]
```

As pointed out in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54446912/2289983), and by [Li-yao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444559/get-all-the-typereps-in-a-value-using-generic-programming?noredirect=1#comment95701102_54444559) this also requires handling lists in a special way, plus defining several other instances, which adds some boilerplate.

Example:

```hs
>>> typeReps ['a']
[[Char],Char]

>>> :set -XDeriveGeneric
>>> data Foo = Foo [Int] (Char, Char) deriving (Generic)
>>> instance HasTypeReps Foo
>>> typeReps $ Foo [1, 2] ('a', 'b')
[Foo,[Int],Int,Int,(Char,Char),Char,Char]
```